# Display a flutter app over other apps from background when phone is locked for Android and iOS (like an alarm app)

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a working prototype (web) for a simple alarm app, when i was researching the part of :

- waking up the screen when its locked,
- show the app and play a sound
- allow user to take action (dismiss, snooze, etc...)

I came across multiple posts asking about this and people replying that it is not possible, at the same time i saw [this alarm package](https://pub.dev/packages/alarm) in pub.dev which basically shows a notification "banner".

What i want to achieve is something similar to all the popular Alarm apps like (Alarmy or Sleep) where the app just fully open in full screen and allow you to do action (dismiss, snooze, captcha, etc...)

is this even possible for Flutter for both iOS and Android ?

Thanks!